# is it possible to detect if the url is pdf which users are surfing and then suggest open with an especial application

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

Hi I am working on an application which it shows pdf using `pdfkit`. I am wondering if its possible to do some how when users surfing web, if the url is kind of `.pdf` , it detects the url and if its pdf, then suggests open with that special application. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user is surfing your app you can detect .PDF form `SFSafariViewController` but when user surfing on safari or any other browser you can not detect it.